# What is the meaning of sizing a logic gate?

Tags: transistors, logic-gates

I am confused with the meaning of sizing the logic gate. I need to size a logic gate using the logical effort method. I searched online that the meaning of sizing using the logical effort means calculating the delay, but I thought I need to find the measurement of the width of nmos and pmos transistors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assignment is to minimize the delay by changing the sizes of the NMOS and PMOS transistors (keeping the PMOS/NMOS width ratio constant for each gate to keep rise/fall times balances).  You don't exactly calculate the delay as it is dependent on specific process parameters.

Do you have some examples to work from in your book or from your instructor? If something in the examples is confusing, you may ask here.

Answer (score 3):

Sizing for example an inverter by a factor 2 means that you make both the NMOS and the PMOS in the inverter 2x as wide. This will behave in the same way as **two** standard (1x) inverters in parallel.

A 2x inverter will have a 2x stronger output meaning it can charge/discharge the load at its output (inputs of other gates) 2x faster.

So let's say that a 1x inverter can drive 10 inputs at a maximum speed of 100 MHz, 
then a 2x inverter can drive that same 10 inputs at 200 MHz **or** it can drive 20 inputs at 100 MHz.

That is roughly the idea.